# Standardize python numbers

Tags: python, data-science

I'm trying to standardize strings representing numbers in a common form so I can compare them. For example, for the following character strings:

```
str_1 = "110000"
str_2 = "110.000"
str_3 = "110 000"
str_4 = "110000,00"
str_5 = "110,000"
str_6 = "110,000.00"
.
.
.
```

the output of the normalization function is always a string representing a number in this format:

```
output_str = "110000.00"
```

For the moment, I tried with several regex but I said to myself that if a simpler solution existed I would be happy to use it. The output of all the above mentioned string should be the same as `output_string`.

Is there a python library that does this? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Three is no one regex for this. Because at least strings 2 and 5 collide depending on locale used. I would suggest parsing the strings to a number with plain python using the appropriate locales and then creating a string from those numbers again.

Comment: You could also achieve this by checking if `str[-3] == '.'` and if not adding a trailing `'.00'`, and stripping all other punctuation from `str[0:-3]`.

Comment: Some locales will use narrow spaces, some will use non-breaking spaces, you also have other grouping patterns like (2,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you, I tested it with all your use cases:

```
import string
def normalizeStr(str_1):
    return str(format(float(str_1.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).replace(' ', '')[:6]), ".2f"))
```

Output:

```
110000.00        <class 'str'>
110000.00        <class 'str'>
110000.00        <class 'str'>
110000.00        <class 'str'>
110000.00        <class 'str'>
110000.00        <class 'str'>
```

###### Hope it helps!

Comment: It's works fine I think or do you want to remove the periods from the string  too and then convert it to a float?

Comment: okay, check the modified answer then, it should work

Comment: Hello, after several tests of your function I noticed that it doesn't work for strings like that : 2.4; 2,4; 2.40 etc

Comment: That's because it was for strings that strictly follow the format given in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If these are localized strings, you can honour whatever [locale number formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/locale.html) the user used. Most of these seem to use English formats. So something like this works:

```py
import locale

oldformat = "110,000.00"
oldloc = locale.getlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC)
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "en_US")
try:
    newformat = f"{locale.atof(oldformat):.2f}"
finally:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, oldloc)
```

(see also: `locale.delocalize`)

Pro:

- Can handle all locales supported by the system
- If you don't set the locale, it uses whatever the user uses, allowing them to customize according to their region

Contra:

- Changing the locale is not thread-safe
- Does not handle `"100 000"` as that is not a valid number in the English locale. I'm not aware of any locales where whitespace is significant within a single number so you might simply want to remove those from the string first
- Since we parse through `float` we can get into floating point trouble if we exceed the range. Consider `f"{locale.atof('100,000,000,000,000,000.99'):.2f}"`. `decimal.Decimal(locale.delocalize('100,000,000,000,000,000.99'))` works, though.

Comment: Regarding whitespace, many locales use a number of whitespace characters for grouping separators. Many applications use CLDR based locales and locale data and whitespace will be the norm for certain locales. Also locale data differs between libc implementations, so number formatting (with grouping separators) can differ between Python on macOS, NetBSD and FreeBSD vs Linux and Windows.

Comment: On macOS, if you change the number to "110.000,00", and the locale to de_DE.UTf-8, you'll get a value error.

Comment: @Andj Sure it will be different depending on the locale. That's why I recommended it *if it is based on the user's locale*. Failure of the examples with a German locale is also expected. That's why I explicitly set it to English.

Comment: on macOS, even if you are using the user locale you'll probably need to reconfigure the thousands_sep to match linux or windows for some locales. Locale based code isn't always cross-platform.

Comment: Its not just that locale data changes between locales, it can change between operating systems for the same locale.

Comment: @Andj My point is that it's what the user is using on their platform.

Comment: I understand, but that is only guaranteed to work if the data was created on the same OS/locale configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For the given input string. You can use this function. If there are other types of string numbers, you may need to add more if statements.

```
def standard_number_str(number_string):
    # remove spaces if there are any inside the string.
    number_string = number_string.replace(' ', '')

    # if there is a '.' in given string but string does not end with '.00'
    # remove the dots
    if '.' in number_string and number_string[-3] != '.':
        number_string = number_string.replace('.', '')

    # if there is a ',' in given string and string ends with ',00'
    # splice the string and get until index -3.
    if ',' in number_string and number_string[-3] == ',':
        number_string = number_string[:-3]

    # remove any remaining commas.
    number_string = number_string.replace(',', '')

    if number_string.endswith('.00'):
        return number_string
    else:
        return number_string + '.00'
```

If this approach is bad. Please comment so that I can learn.